# Why is the notion of k-closed subsets well defined?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

As a standard notion in algebraic topology, for a space $X$, we define a subset $V\subset X$ to be k-closed, if for any compact Hausdorff space $K$ and continuous map $g:K \rightarrow X$, $g^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $K$.

However, I'm not getting how this is well defined. For example, to formally write down the set of k-closed subsets of $X$, we may want to write:
$$\{V\subset X:\forall K,g,K\text{ compact Hausdorff},g:K \rightarrow X\text{ continuous} \implies g^{-1}(V)\text{ closed} \}$$
There seems to be too many such space $K$'s. Do set theory axioms allow for such a construction that requires testing over a proper class of objects?

Comment: I asked this once. You're allowed, apparently, in ZFC to quantify over the entire universe or something like that. This is ok

Comment: Quantifying over entire universe is of course allowed. This goes down to the fundaments of mathematics. For example the axiom of pairing can be written as $\forall x\forall y\exists z((x\in z)\wedge (y\in z))$. This means that both $\forall x$ and $\forall y$ are allowed. Quantifying over universe is different from creating sets.

Comment: Hmmm. So those type of constructions are actually allowed. That makes sense.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/315068 this may be helpful